# Ruby Koans : About_Scoring_Project (Precisely, iterator with .map method)

Tags: ruby

I'm new in Ruby. I got some problems when I was working through the Ruby Koans, the About_Scoring_Project. The .map method returns value depending on the order of phrase, not the name of variable. I am confused...

```
def score(dice)
  total_score = 0
  side = 6
  count = Array.new
  side.times{count << 0} # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

  # Tell the occured time of each side
  while i = dice.pop
    count[i-1] += 1
  end

  # Calculating total score

  i = 0

  count.map! do |item|
    i += 1
    if item >= 3 && i != 1
      total_score = i*100
      item - 3
    elsif item >= 3
      total_score = 1000
      item - 3
    else
      item
    end
  end

  # Count the rest
  total_score += ( count[0]*100 + count[4]*50 )

  total_score # return the total score
end
```

Although this one works, but when I originally wrote :

```
  elsif item >= 3
  item - 3
  total_score = 1000
```

The array count turned out to be [1000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] when executing

```
  score([1,1,1]) # score([1,1,1]) = 101000 which should be 1000
```

That's to say it gave the value 1000 to item not to total_value. But it works correctly when I changed the order of the two phrases like what is indicated above. Could someone help me with this please. I am new in Ruby and programming. Forgive my broken English...

The context of the project :

```
# Greed is a dice game where you roll up to five dice to accumulate
# points.  The following "score" function will be used to calculate the
# score of a single roll of the dice.
#
# A greed roll is scored as follows:
#
# * A set of three ones is 1000 points
#
# * A set of three numbers (other than ones) is worth 100 times the
#   number. (e.g. three fives is 500 points).
#
# * A one (that is not part of a set of three) is worth 100 points.
#
# * A five (that is not part of a set of three) is worth 50 points.
#
# * Everything else is worth 0 points.
#
#
# Examples:
#
# score([1,1,1,5,1]) => 1150 points
# score([2,3,4,6,2]) => 0 points
# score([3,4,5,3,3]) => 350 points
# score([1,5,1,2,4]) => 250 points
#
# More scoring examples are given in the tests below:
#
# Your goal is to write the score method.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The .map method returns value depending on the order of phrase, not the name of variable. I am confused...

More or less, yes. A block simply returns the value of the last expression evaluated, pretty much like a method.

If you have:

```
count.map! do |item|
  item - 3
  total_score = 1000
end
```

then `total_score = 1000` which evaluates to `1000` is the block's return value.

If you have:

```
count.map! do |item|
  total_score = 1000
  item - 3
end
```

then `item - 3` is the block's return value.

`map!` in turn creates a new array containing the values from the block.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I am really astonished that in Ruby it works like that ! The iterator receives the value that blocks return (If I have correctly understood). Is there any better way to improve it ? Like using instance variable ? I am really a beginner...

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way :

```
def three_of_a_kind(dice, count)
  count * (dice == 1 ? 1000 : 100 * dice)
end

def no_set(dice, count)
  case dice
  when 1
    count * 100
  when 5
    count * 50
  else
    0
  end
end

def score(rolls)
  rolls.group_by(&:itself).map do |dice, throws|
    n = throws.size
    three_of_a_kind(dice, n / 3) + no_set(dice, n % 3)
  end.inject(:+)
end

p score([1, 1, 1, 5, 1]) == 1150
p score([2, 3, 4, 6, 2]) == 0
p score([3, 4, 5, 3, 3]) == 350
p score([1, 5, 1, 2, 4]) == 250
```

By the way :

```
  side = 6
  count = Array.new
  side.times{count << 0}
```

is just :

```
Array.new(6){ 0 }
```

Comment: Wow ! This solution looks beautiful and leaves everything for methods ! Great ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
def score(dice)
  sum = 0
  dice.tally.each do |x, n|
    sum += n / 3 * (x == 1 ? 1000 : x * 100) + n % 3 * (x == 1 ? 100 : x == 5 ? 50 : 0)
  end
  sum
end
```